# User relationships are corrupting my sessions in Symfony2

Tags: session, symfony

My users have a number of relationships setup in Doctrine but one in particular  seems to be causing me a lot of problems, each user can have a number of memberships and each membership has a membership type.

For some reason however when I load those memberships it seems to be nuking my session, I login and get presented with a "Your Account" page as I should do but if I refresh the page I get sent back to the login screen. My sessions are stored in the database so I've been checking them to see what happens and this is what I'm seeing:

1. Session starts off empty
2. I login but make sure I get redirected to a page that doesn't load memberships
3. Session now contains user object and all info about relationships
4. I visit "Your Account" which loads memberships, they get displayed correctly.
5. Session has been nuked and is now as it was in step 1
6. I refresh the page and get sent back to the login page

I've defined my own user provider and I noticed if I set the membership type on each membership to null in refreshUser it starts working so I'm guessing the session is having trouble with that relationship.

I'm really struggling to find a solution to this so any help would be really appreciated.

EDIT: Been doing some more experimenting and found if I switch to file sessions everything starts working so it must be related to storing sessions in the database. I made the switch using the guide in the Symfony Cookbook. For reference here are the relevant bits from my config.yml:

```
framework:
    session: 
        default_locale: %locale%
        auto_start:     true
        storage_id:   session.storage.pdo

 parameters:
    pdo.db_options:
        db_table:       session
        db_id_col:      session_id
        db_data_col:    session_value
        db_time_col:    session_time

 session.storage.pdo:
    class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\SessionStorage\PdoSessionStorage
    arguments: [@pdo, %session.storage.options%, %pdo.db_options%]
 pdo:
    class: PDO
    arguments:
        dsn:      "mysql:dbname=%database_name%;host=%database_host%"
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
```

Everything else about them seems fine so maybe it's a bug in PdoSessionStorage

Answer (score 0):

It might be in you equals method that is too strict. if you do $user === $otherUser; and the object have changed (the relation isnt a collection with proxies anymore) it would return false.

Comment: Hi Henrik, I don't think that's it. At the moment my equals check is just comparing id (hoping to improve that later), I've just tried logging every response from it and it's always returning true.